# Externs and DLL imports

Tags: dllimport, extern

I have this rather strange looking couple of lines in my code, that I am trying to decipher.  Does anyone know what it says?

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);
```

Comment: Its a call to the Windows API, take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1285/Calling-API-functions-using-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is known as Platform Invoke, basically it's just making the function GetPrivateProfileString from kernel32.dll available to your program.  Check out http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetPrivateProfileString for a little more information on that specific function.